# I'm installing flutter - parse error near \n

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install flutter, but I'm having trouble with updating the [path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path).

```
 ~ % echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
 ~ % export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter/bin/zsh"
 ~ % source $HOME/.<rc file>
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are writing your path to Flutter in this section:

```
   PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY
```

It will be something like this:

```
    /Users/yourUserName/Downloads/
```

I assume again, your username is containing space characters. So, you can use single quotes. Like this:

```
    export PATH="$PATH:'[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]'/flutter/bin/zsh'"
```

Answer (score 0):

easy fix, you are unintentionally leaving space between exports!!!